# Blazor WASM client and loading of javascript files

Tags: javascript, blazor, webassembly

I am debugging my WASM client and using a few javascript files.  Not all of them get loaded into the browser every time, and there is a pattern to this:

The first time I use a certain browser, like Chrome, it loads the javascript files it finds.  And it updates them when I update them.  But if add another javascript file, it doesn't seem to pick up on it automatically.  I have do a ctrl-F5 to get this latest file.  And I have to do it every single time.

But if I use a different browser, that has never had this app loaded in, it finds all of the files and updates them as expected. But if I add another file, then same problem.  If it wasn't in the wwwroot when I first used the browser, it never seems to get included automatically.